# For what values of m are the roots of $x^2 +2x+3 = m(2x+1)$ real and positive

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

I am only able to show that to be real, $m <-1$ or $m\geq2$
Don't know how to finish solution
Answer is $2 \leq m < 3$

So far:

After expanding and factorising,

$x^2 + 2(1-m)x + (3-m) = 0  $

Roots are real if discriminant $\ge 0 $

i.e. $4(m-2)(m+1)>=0  $

Therefore $m ≤ -1 \text{ or } m \ge 2$ for roots to be real

However I don't know how to find m for roots to be positive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the equation to have positive and real roots, two extra conditions are needed
$$2m-2>0$$ $$3-m>0$$ 
$$\therefore 1<m<3$$
Taking the intersection of the intervals found, we will get $$\therefore 2 \leq m <3$$
:)

Comment: The coefficient of the second term is the negative of the sum of roots. The coefficient of the third term is the product of roots. For more information, you can search more information on the "Theory of Equations"

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks so much. Yes I didn't realise the use of sum and product of roots. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Notice your equation is the same as $$x^2 + x(2 - 2m) + (3 -m) =  0$$

Now, by the quadratic equation, the points where this parabola is zero, that means the zeros of the equations are:

$$ x = \frac{2m - 2 \pm \sqrt{4 - 8m + 4m^2 -12 +4m}}{2} $$

We only need to care about the determinant $\Delta(m) = 4m^2 -4m - 8$. You can see this equation geometrically or algebraically, whichever suits your tastes. But The determinant has the following properties: If the $\Delta$ of a quadration equation iz $0$, then you get unique solution. if $\Delta < 0 $, then we have no real solution. If $\Delta > 0$, then we have 2 solutions. Use this info to solve your problem.

HINT: Graph $\Delta(m) = 4m^2 -4m - 8$

Comment: Yep, I got stuck here. This is where it gets hard. After you solve for m, you get m <=-1 or m>=2 (for roots to be real). I don't know how to show that roots are positive.

Answer (score 1):

Denoting the discriminant by $D(m) := 4(m+1)(m-2)$, we have for the roots 
$$ x_{1,2} = (m-1) \pm \sqrt{D(m)} $$
as you say correctly, the roots are real for $D(m) \ge 0$. And the roots are both positive if $0 \le \sqrt{D(m)} \le m-1$, so $m \ge 1$ and $D(m) \le (m-1)^2$ must hold. Now try to solve the last inequality for $m$.

Comment: Very nice method

Answer (score 0):

$x^2 +2x+3 = m(2x+1)$

$x^2 +2(1-m)x+3-m = 0$

$D=b^2-4ac$

$D=4(1-m)^2-4(3-m)$

$D=4(1+m^2-2m)-12+4m$

$D=4+4m^2-8m)-12+4m$

$D=4m^2-4m-8$

For $D \geq 0$,you will find real roots

roots are real for  $m ≤ -1 \text{ or } m \ge 2$------(1)

$ x = (m-1) \pm \sqrt{m^2-m-2} $

roots are positive if $(m-1)>\sqrt{m^2-m-2}$

$m<3$---------------(2)

Combining (1) and (2) condition ,we get

roots are real and positive if $  2 \leq m<3$

Comment: No you don't. for D>= 0 you get m <= -1 or m >= 2. This does not show that the roots are positive, only real.

Comment: I thought ,you mean real roots

Comment: Nope, real AND positive. It is quite tricky the positive part :L